# A fold bug on vimerl

Tags: vim, erlang, vim-plugin, folding, rebar

I use the vim plugin [vimerl](https://github.com/jimenezrick/vimerl) to code Erlang.

Today I find a fold bug when reading the source code of [rebar](https://github.com/rebar/rebar)

It appears on the function commands/0 in line 414 of [rebar.erl](https://github.com/rebar/rebar/blob/master/src/rebar.erl).
I roughly read the [erlang.vim](https://github.com/jimenezrick/vimerl/blob/master/ftplugin/erlang.vim), found it is because the line 454 of rebar.erl

```
 _tests module.
```

matchs the regx

```
s:erlang_fun_end   = '^[^%]*\.\s*\(%.*\)\?$'
```

It seems there is no method to fix this bug, because vim fold lines one by one and can not know it is a string.

Do you think so?